# Как выровнять блок по центру с pos absolute и width auto?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
    div {
       background: lightgray;
       position: relative;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       left: 100px;
    }

    span {
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        background: red;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <span>Тут произвольный текст</span>
</div>
```

Нужно выровнять по горизонтали блок с текстом так, чтобы был по центру, так (заранее скажу, что вместо div будет ячейка таблицы `TD`):

span - необязательно должен быть absolute, если есть другие варианты, то подойдет. Суть в том, чтобы если ширина блока текста больше чем сама ячейка, то блок с текстом выходил за границы блока таблицы, как на первой картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.parent-box {
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Aloha</span>
    </td>
    <td class="parent-box">
      <span class="child">Тут произвольный текст</span>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: от души, бро, обнял

Comment: Рад помочь, обращайтесь))

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно в коде прописать блоки в последовательности серый`<td>` потом ниже тега `</table>`
Создайте красный блок Div и добавьте стиль margin-top:-??px; (размер пикселей сами подгоните так чтобы красный блок лег на td ) и у вас получиться накладывание красного независимого блока по верх серого и при растяжке текстом красного блока он выйдет за рамки серого